# Disable inline and cell editing and only allow form editing in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid which maintains mappings of meta data of some entity (e.g. a document). In such a case, we just have add or edit. Editing is to be done just to inactivate record

Since this is the case, we have no point using cell or inline editing. Form editing option will be the best

However, these forms show only those columns which have "editable: true"

So, how does one disable editing in the grid and enable it only for the form?

onSelectRow does not fire at all. Am I missing something??? I am using jqgrid 3.8

This is what I have tried:

```
var metaGrid = jQuery("#" + nodeMetaDataGrid);
        metaGrid.jqGrid({
            pager: jQuery("#" + nodeMetaDataGridPager),
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            sortname: 'Id',
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [50, 100, 'ALL'],
            sortorder: "asc",
            height: "auto",
            autowidth: true,
            colNames: ['Id', 'Meta Data Type', 'Meta Data Value', 'Status', 'Date Added', 'Date Removed'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, key: true },
              { name: 'MetaType', index: 'MetaType', width: 30, editable: false, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: "My/GetList"} },
              { name: 'MetaValue', index: 'MetaValue', width: 30, editable: false, editrules: { required: true} },
              { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 10, editable: false, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "A:Active;I:Inactive"} },
              { name: 'DateAdded', index: 'DateAdded', width: 20, editable: false },
              { name: 'DateRemoved', index: 'DateRemoved', width: 20, editable: false }
              ],
            datatype: 'json',
            viewrecords: true,
            mtype: 'GET',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                userdata: "userdata"
            },
            url: getUrl,
            multiselect: false,
            //editurl: "someurl"
            caption: "Available Meta Data",
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                alert("Before Iff statement");
                if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                    alert("hi, selected");
                    jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel);
                    var cm = metaGrid.jqGrid('getColProp', 'MetaType');
                    cm.editable = false;
                    //grid.jqGrid('addRow', id, true, null, null, 'someURL');
                    //cm.editable = true;
                    lastSel = id;
                }
            }
        })
        .navGrid("#" + nodeMetaDataGridPager, { view: false, del: false, add: true, edit: true, search: false },
           {
               //Edit mode
               height: 150,
               reloadAfterSubmit: true,
               modal: true,
               closeOnEscape: true,
               url: "someURL"                   
           },
           {   //Add mode
               height: "auto",
               reloadAfterSubmit: false,
               modal: true,
               closeOnEscape: true,
               url: "someURL",                   
               recreateForm: true,
               //trying to use this because onSelectRow does not fire
               beforeShowForm: function (form) {                       
                   var cm = metaGrid.jqGrid('getColProp', 'MetaType');                       
                   cm.editable = true;
               }
           },
           {     
                //Delete mode                  
           },
           {
           //View mode               
           }
         );
```

Thanks,
Apploader

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can just delete this statement:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
                alert("Before Iff statement");
                if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                    alert("hi, selected");
                    jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel);
                    var cm = metaGrid.jqGrid('getColProp', 'MetaType');
                    cm.editable = false;
                    //grid.jqGrid('addRow', id, true, null, null, 'someURL');
                    //cm.editable = true;
                    lastSel = id;
                }
```

and add "cellEdit:false"

Answer (score 0):

As kayla indicated, remove your onSelectRow block and use cellEdit... http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing